# Automatic Properties not compiling despite adding reference to System.Core.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties

I have a c# v3.5 framework site that I am doing some maintenance on. I wish to use Automatic Properties but whenever I try to add one, the compiler fails [as below]. I *have* added the System.Core.dll (and it is in the web.config ok) but still no joy.

Anyway seen this behavior before and have a resolution?

Thanks,

## dan

Error 6 
'XXX.Archive.TypeOfArchive.get' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern

============

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your application is still being compiled with 2.0 version of the compiler. If it is a web application, you may need to configure the compiler in web.config. See for example [this question](http://forums.asp.net/p/1186042/2023770.aspx).

Also, you shouldn't need `System.Core.dll` to get automatic properties working. Unlike LINQ, automatic properties are purely a feature of the compiler and don't depend on any types from .NET 3.5 libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the web.config setup to use the 3.5 compiler?  It looks like it's still invoking a .0 compiler to build.  Example config for C#, place this below `</system.web>`:

```
<system.codedom>
  <compilers>
     <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider,System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
     </compiler>         
  </compilers>
```

Reference config: https://web.archive.org/web/20211020153237/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/121207-1.aspx

Comment: thanks! that did it (marked prev. post as answer but yours was very complete just posted slightly later, much appreciated nick)